# hyperlink list from database columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I have a mysql database with my movies

```
id | movietitle | year | imdbnumber
```

I want to display my movies as a hyperlink list with a php sql query

like this

```
<a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/ttIMDBNUMBER/" target="_blank">MOVIETITLE (YEAR)</a><br>
```

i want them sorted and grouped by letter

Example:

```
T
Titanic (1997)
THX 1138 (1971)

U
Underworld (2003)
...
```

how can I do that in php?

Comment: what have you tried / what's your PHP level (have no clue, beginner, intermediate, etc.)?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: MySQLi might be easier initially. Then PDO.

Comment: Haha, ok, then: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list using the SQL query itself using `ORDER BY`.

Once you have the data out of the DB, you can create each of the hyperlinks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt<?=$imdbnumber?>/" target="_blank"><?=$movietitle?> <?=$year?></a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regular expressions, this is one of the solutions.

```
<?php
$movie[0]='Amber';
$movie[1]='babar';
$movie[2]='Aviator';
$movie[3]='Caty boy';

function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return !strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle));
}

foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i){
    echo '<h1>'.strtoupper($i).'</h1>';
    foreach($movie as $key){
        if(startsWith(strtolower($key),$i)){
            echo '<li>'.$key.'</li>';
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Output for above would be :

```
A
Amber
Aviator
B
Babar
C
Caty boy
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

Populate your $movie array from the database of course with ORDER BY SQL query. Then $movie array can be in this format

```
Title - (Year)
```

It won't make a difference what you put after the title - year or any other detail. The condition is that your string should start with the title. SO even if you miss out the format, Ex:

```
$movie[0]='Titanic';
$movie[1]='Hulk (2009)';
```

still the function should sort it in the manner you described in your problem statement. Hope it helps.